# Fastest way to move vertices with python

Tags: python, vertices

I'm still a python beginner and I'm writing a script/addon that moves vertices of a mesh following a "long" calcul every time frame changes. Something like :

```
import bpy

def MoveVertices(scene):
    obj = bpy.data.objects['Cube4']
    '''creating a copied mesh (.to_mesh) here to retrieve vertices positions later
    '+ setting some variables
    '''
    for v in obj.data.vertices:
        '''long calcul to find the vector
        ' like 20 lines of code some if statements and calculus
        '''
        v.co += vector
    ''' setting some variables + removing tmp mesh (.remove)'''
    return {'FINISHED'}

def register():
    bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_post.clear()
    bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_post.append(MoveVertices)

def unregister():
    bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_post.remove(MoveVertices)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

What happens of course is when there is a lot of vertices the system starts to slow down a lot. I know for performance sake I should write in C/C++ and do a custom blender build but I was wondering if there isn't a more efficient way to move bunch of vertices in "real time" with python.

Here are my questions :

1. does a straight loop through all vertices like I'm doing is the best
   way to go concerning calcul speed?
2. would using bmesh help in that matter?
3. what about slicing the amount of vertices and launching the calcul
   in parallel for each chunks (with a modal timer operator) ? Would that be an idea ?
4. is there something I'm missing in the python api that could help ?

Thx a lot for your help.

Comment: Is it correct that you want to move every vertex of your mesh by the **same vector**? Is the mesh in edit or object mode?

Comment: well the value of "vector" changes actually for each vertex depending on my calcul : vector = f(frame,other parameters set by object custom properties and vertex weight). The mesh is in object mode. thank you for any help. –

Comment: You may wanna use `foreach_set()`, that's the only chance to speed it up.

Comment: Blindingly optimizing is never a good idea, have you tried using the cProfile Python module to isolate where the bottleneck is?

Comment: Thx guys! @CoDEmanX, I'll have a look at {foreach_set()}, it is interesting as it seems to be faster than looping through all vertices with {.co}. Mike Pan, I never used cProfile before but there is a 1st time for everything :D Let you know how it goes.

Comment: @CoDEmanX `foreach_set()` is very interesting but it seems to work only on `.data.vertices` collection (or more largely for bpy_prop_collection). Do you know by any chance if there is a way of using it on a set of vertices or can we create a bpy_prop_collection from a set of vertices ? Thx !

Comment: It can only be run on all vertices, that's what makes it fast. You can assign the current value if you want to keep certain as-is.

Comment: hmmm so i guess I can't do something like `bpy.types.Mesh.MyVertLayer = bpy.props.CollectionProperty(type=)` with the type being "vertex" to define a collection of vertices that I would fill with the vertices I want ? Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`foreach_set()` is actually very fast but not usable in my case because I'm not always going through all vertices in all cases.
It seems that the "for" loop is the best way to go.

Using bmesh actually is a little faster because it doen't refresh the scene each time the script changes the location of a vertex.

Thx @CoDEmanX and  @MikePan for the help.